# How can i split my List<List<Class>> to store it in another list?

Tags: c#, wpf, list

I'm trying to fill my

```
List<List<Class>> items1 = new List<List<Class>>();
```

All the Values are in a text file called "TextFileItems1.txt" like this.

```
2
33
50
0
Termina Especie
1
72
0
1
Termina Especie
2
31
50
0
Termina Especie
2
32
50
0
Termina Especie
2
27
50
0
Termina Especie
2
37
50
0
Termina Especie
2
33
50
0
Termina Especie
2
20
50
0
Termina Especie
2
44
50
0
Termina Especie
2
29
50
0
Termina Especie
```

And so on ... I have 960 elements

My problem is the main list length has to be equal to a variable called Length1 and the sublist length has to be equal to a variable called Length2, example

```
 Length1 = 40;
 Length2 = 24;
```

My problem is, how can I split the text file in order to insert 40 MainList and 24 SubList into items1?

Class

```
 public class cEspecie
 {
   private string name;
   private int lifetime;
   private int movility;
   private int deadto;
    private int type;

 public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return name;
    }
    set
    {
        name= value;
    }
}
 public int Type
 {
    get
    {
        return type;
    }
    set
    {
        type = value;
    }
}
public int LifeTime
{
    get
    {
        return lifetime;
    }
    set
    {
        lifetime= value;
    }
}
public int Movility
{
    get
    {
        return movility;
    }
    set
    {
        movility = value;
    }
}
public int DeadTo
{
    get
    {
        return deadto;
    }
    set
    {
        deadto = value;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: can you  explain  a bit more please what you mean by  MainList and SubList

Comment: Show your actual code

Comment: Due to I have a List<List<Class>> the first list its my MainList and the second one is my SubList.

Comment: Ok main List is the outher list. I see.

Comment: we still did  not  understand how you want to fill  the Main list for example  have you  a marker

Comment: Just read the text file line by line. Every 4 lines you'd create a `cEspecie` instance, populate it and add it to a `List<cEspecie>`. Once you're done with the text file split this List to make a new `List` of `List<cEspecie>`.

Comment: I want to point out a few things. First, those properties should probably be auto-properties, Second, `cEspecie` breaks c# naming convention and should be called simply `Especie`. Hungarian notation notation makes no sense in the age of strong typing and first-class IDEs. Finally - and I cannot emphasize this enough - `List<T>` is only for a case when you intend to have the user add objects directly to it. In this case you probably want `IEnumerable<T>`, `ImmutableList<T>` (from Bcl.Immutables), or a simple T[][]. Its usage is **not** the same as in java.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a really simple one using LINQ, a creative for loop, and generators. [Here it is on Complify](https://compilify.net/3jp/2)

```
public static class EnumerationExtensions {
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitIntoGroupsOfSize<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection, int ofSize) {
    for(
        IEnumerable<T> remainingCollection = collection; 
        remainingCollection.Count() > 0; 
        remainingCollection = remainingCollection.Skip(ofSize) ) {
            yield return remainingCollection.Take(ofSize);
        }
}
}

var collection = Enumerable.Range(1, 22).ToArray();
var groups = EnumerationExtensions.SplitIntoGroupsOfSize(collection, ofSize: 4);
var res = String.Join("\n-------------\n", groups.Select(g => String.Join(", ", g) ) );
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

I would probably make it as an extension method in a real project since that's expected for this sort of thing but complify has problems with these.

With your parameters a recursive solution would also probably work but you know...c# has no tail-call optimization so...

explanation: consider that a for loop is *really* just a special case of a while loop

```
for(initial condition; while this is true; do this before each but the first iteration) {}
```

Turns out that in this case this is very similar to what we need, but not with the standard integer index setup, instead the third condition is simply to track what we values have not yet been returned.

The yield keyword basically is a simpler way of creating an enumerator. In fact, that's exactly what it gets compiled to. so every time a foreach loop (or a Select(), etc) calls `enumerator.MoveNext()` we run the code until we hit the next `yield return`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a single LINQ query to create `List<List<cEspecie>>` with inner list of count `Length2`:

```
var result =
File.ReadAllLines("TextFile.txt")
    .Select((line, i) => new { Line = line, LineNumber = i })
    .GroupBy(a => a.LineNumber / 5,
             a => a.Line,
            (key, values) => new 
            {
                Number = key,
                Class = new cEspecie()
                {
                    LifeTime = int.Parse(values.ElementAt(0)),
                    Movility = int.Parse(values.ElementAt(1)),
                    DeadTo = int.Parse(values.ElementAt(2)),
                    Type = int.Parse(values.ElementAt(3)),
                    Name = values.ElementAt(4)
                }
            })
    .GroupBy(a => a.Number / Length2,
             a => a.Class,
             (key, values) => values.ToList())
    .ToList();
```

You will probably set properties with different elements order because I do not know the order.

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Program
   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        List<cEspecie> cEspecieList = new List<cEspecie>();
        string[] myEspecieFile = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt");

        List<cEspecie> mainList = new List<cEspecie>(); 
        //here you can do the some for the sublist 
        for (int i = 0; i < myEspecieFile.Length; i=i+5)
        {

            cEspecie ces = new cEspecie()
            {
                Name = myEspecieFile[i],
                LifeTime = int.Parse(myEspecieFile[i + 1]),
                Movility = int.Parse(myEspecieFile[i + 2]),
                DeadTo = int.Parse(myEspecieFile[i + 3]),
                Type = int.Parse(myEspecieFile[i + 4])
            };

            mainList.Add(ces);                
        }

        // and then you can  iterate through  your mainList to add sub list  something  like this  
        foreach (var item in mainList)
        {
            item.cSubEspecieList = mainList;  
        }


    }

}
public class cEspecie
{
    private string name;
    private int lifetime;
    private int movility;
    private int deadto;
    private int type;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }
    public int Type
    {
        get
        {
            return type;
        }
        set
        {
            type = value;
        }
    }
    public int LifeTime
    {
        get
        {
            return lifetime;
        }
        set
        {
            lifetime = value;
        }
    }
    public int Movility
    {
        get
        {
            return movility;
        }
        set
        {
            movility = value;
        }
    }
    public int DeadTo
    {
        get
        {
            return deadto;
        }
        set
        {
            deadto = value;
        }
    }
    //you need only this property in oreder to create sublist 
    public List<cEspecie> cSubEspecieList
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```